# Set entity subentity withoud load from repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine entity which has categories so to set a category to the entity i need to call

```
$category = $categoryRepository->find($categoryId);
$entity->addCategory($category);
```

Is it possible to set it without the repository with only the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use reference proxies:

```
$entity->addCategory($em->getReference('MyProject\Model\Category', $categoryId))
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies

Comment: thank you for your answer. so the entitymanager is required and I can not do it directly in my entity because their exists no entitymanager. To make it more clear my idea was to create a setData function in the entity which basically is a array from a JSON api. In my case I have also some other endpoints which have the same logic I thought to move the whole set into the entity so id can be easy used where the entity is loaded.

Comment: @AlexanderSchranz entity shouldn't know about entity manager because it violates SRP principle, entity should be only container for data with database mapping. Just write symfony service that will convert data from JSON to entity. It can also handle data validation and formating.